# TFS 2013 Checkin Policy

Tags: tfs

I am trying to associate every changed set with a work item field.
I was able to associate the changeset with work items type... that was not enough for our type. and we're trying to be more specific and associate it with a field of a work item to enhance traceability.

any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't believe there is a way to do this, even a custom link type isn't going to help.

The changeset is linked to a Work Item but not a specific field.  You could perhaps do something with a custom field on the work item that stores a field name and a changeset id but in reality I think it would be a rubbish experience.

I'd question why you'd want to do this and suggest you look at how you manage your requirements and development tasks.

Comment: Thank you rerwinRR.       We want to follow this approach because we want to track every change in our releases with a work item field that identify that change. linking with a work item will not be very accurate.